# Can I add pseudo element objects to Material UI custom theme config?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

In my file `themeConfig.js` I have declared some theme variables that I use throughout my app to style various components. I need to use the scrollbar `-webkit` to persist a scrollbar for certain components. The `-webkit` styles are long and bulky, so I want to be able to add them to my `themeConfig.js` file. These scrollbar styles are pseudo-elements and while I can assign them, I haven't been able to figure out how to use them in `themeConfig.js`.

*themeConfig.js*

```
const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  layout: {
    header: 64,
    sideNav: 45,
    mainDivHeight: 250,
    ...
  }
})

export default myTheme
```

*ComponentExample.js*

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const ComponentExample = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <div className={classes.mainDiv}>I'm a div</div>
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  mainDiv: {
    height: theme.layout.mainDivHeight,
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: 8,
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)',
      webkitBoxShadow: 'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)',
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)',
      outline: '1px solid slategrey',
      borderRadius: 7,
    },
  }
}))

export default ComponentExample
```

It would be great if I could stuff this into a variable in my theme file and apply it to a component:

```
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: 8,
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      boxShadow: 'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)',
      webkitBoxShadow: 'inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)',
    },
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)',
      outline: '1px solid slategrey',
      borderRadius: 7,
    },
```

But the way theme styles are declared in `makeStyles`, there is a 1:1 property assignment and I don't know how to gracefully apply a whole style object like that to a component. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The styles declared in `makeStyles` are within an object and that object can be constructed in any of the ways JavaScript supports. The way I would handle this is to put the styles that you want to use within a single object in the theme (`scrollbarStyles` in my example below) and then use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in the place where you want to use it within `makeStyles`.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const myTheme = createMuiTheme({
  layout: {
    header: 64,
    sideNav: 45,
    mainDivHeight: 250,
    scrollbarStyles: {
      overflowY: "scroll",
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
        width: 8
      },
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
        boxShadow: "inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)",
        webkitBoxShadow: "inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.00)"
      },
      "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.2)",
        outline: "1px solid slategrey",
        borderRadius: 7
      }
    }
  }
});

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  mainDiv: {
    ...theme.layout.scrollbarStyles,
    height: theme.layout.mainDivHeight
  }
}));
function ComponentExample() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.mainDiv}>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        I'm a div with enough content to make me scroll
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        I'm a div with enough content to make me scroll
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        I'm a div with enough content to make me scroll
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        I'm a div with enough content to make me scroll
      </div>
      <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
        I'm a div with enough content to make me scroll
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <ComponentExample />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit scrollbar styles in theme]